# send data from phone to server

Tags: sqlite, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am trying to develop an android mobile application using the PhoneGap framework, and I want to synchronize my table  of local database(of my phone) to the server database.

this is my code, but this code allow me to send only one line of table how can i send all line of table.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: col1+'&amp;lid='+col2,
        url: 'http://your-domain.com/comments/save.php',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            alert('Your data was successfully added');
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log(data);
            alert('There was an error adding your data');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry for my miss understoods...

If you are using phonegap i guess you are using the Storage feature: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage

folowing one of theirs examples, you can do something like:

```
function queryDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DEMO', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
}

function querySuccess(tx, results) {

    //do you ajax request....
    ...
    data: {
        rows : results.rows
    }
    ...
}

function errorCB(err) {
    alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
}

var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
```

---

other option is to send a simple array...

```
function querySuccess(tx, results) {

  var myRowsIds = [];


  var len = results.rows.length;
        for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
            myRowsIds .push( results.rows.item(i).id )
        }

        //do you ajax request....
        ...
        data: {
                rows : myRowsIds
            }
        ...
    }
```

hope it helps!

Comment: yes, in the php file you use $_POST['rows'] to get an json string. you can parse that string as an object. as an alternative, just pass a string with the ids, delimited by a character.

Comment: Hey this code not working.. !! :P
It will work if you convert the  rows : results.rows as rows: JSON.stringify(results.rows).

Answer (score 2):

Try to select the data from the localDatabase and send it row by row, here's an example:

```
 db.transaction(function(tx) {
    Squery = 'SELECT * FROM news WHERE category_id ='+lid;
        tx.executeSql(Squery,
            null,
            function(tx, results)
            {
                    for(i=0; i<results.rows. length; i++){
                        row = results.rows.item(0);
                                $.ajax({ -- your code using row['name_of_column'] -- })
                              }
                        },
                        console.log('error')
            });});
```